# Object.freeze and Array Notation inside Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

Someone please illuminate me how this works.

Is `[taskTypes.wind.printer_3d]` a way to set the property of an object?

Is `["windFarm"]` an array with one element?

Trying to understand someone else's undocumented code in a big project is super depressing.

```
const keysForBigOutputData = Object.freeze({
    wind: {
        [taskTypes.wind.printer_3d]: ["windFarm"],
    }
.....
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct on both fronts.

`keysForBigOutputData.wind` will be an object with a property named after the value of `taskTypes.wind.printer_3d`.

`["foo"]` is a one element array.